# Case insensitive comparison in VBA using VisibleItemsList

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying to do is to filter a pivot table acording to a given string. The data in the pivot field (from a cube) may contain `"SOME STRING"` or `"soME sTrInG"`, both representing the same.

So how do I make this code case insensitive to match any possible typing?

```
variable = "Some STRING"
ActiveWorksheet.PivotTables("table1").PivotFields( _
        "[foo].[boo].[goo]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[foo].[boo].&[" & variable & "]")
```

Comment: `UCASE()` will make the string be in all uppercase, so you can compare variations of upper/lowercase characters.  Note that, to my knowledge, pivot tables are not inherently case sensitive, so depending how you compare will make a difference.

Comment: `UCASE()` is easy to use in a normal pivot table as I can access the items of a pivot field comparing `UCase(variable)` and `UCase(.PivotFields("pf").PivotItems("item").Value)`, but in my case the comparison is done in `VisibleItemsList` so I'm not accessing each item by myself.

Comment: Whoever is responsible for that cube needs to fix their stuff. Once it's in a pivot table, the data should have been cleansed a looooong time ago. A pivot table that's off a SSAS data cube shouldn't ever need to deal with `"SOME STRING"` representing the same thing as `"soME sTrInG"`. Ever.

Comment: Failing an ETL and data mart that's actually doing its job, I'd try use PowerQuery and see if I can fix the data, instead of patching things up and working around the cube issues. Really, that's a cube issue, not a PivotTable or VBA problem.

Comment: Great suggestion. Actually PowerPivot has a function UCase so that can fix the data before it gets to the cube.

Answer (score 0):

I force upper case on everything in VBA using `UCase()`. Then I ensure the comparisons I'm doing are all upper case.

I don't remember if this works in Pivot tables as I never use them; but assuming

```
var1 = "HEY"
var2 = UCase(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").cells(1,1).value2)
```

You can store variables like that I'd just use `UCase()`.

Comment: `UCASE()` is easy to use in a normal pivot table as I can access the items of a pivot field comparing `UCase(variable)` and `UCase(.PivotFields("pf").PivotItems("item").Value)`, but in my case the comparison is done in `VisibleItemsList` so I'm not accessing each item by myself.

Comment: Interesting, this is why I've always avoided using pivot tables. Can you get the data out of the pivot table as a regular cell? Honestly it's why I've always hated Pivot tables. I'd get it out of the pivot table, and do my work, and put it back. Is that possible for you?

Comment: Actually my problem is not the pivot table, is "the pivot table from the cube" which forces me to use `VisibleItemsList` instead of a simple for-loop through every item switching on/off their `Visible` property.